# Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

Tags: sql-server, datetime

I'm trying to execute the following query, and it shows me the error in the title,I'm not converting date or time here.Not sure why its showing the error.

```
select *    
from [dbo].[Data]    
where [Report Month] between '2015-05-01' and '2015-06-31'     
  and [FTE Status]='Inactive'
```

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no such day as June 31st.

Comment: My bad,Thank you Bud!